# extending Zend_form_element_select, the errors disappear

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I have a drop down `Element_Select` that I'm turning into a custom element `Element_SelectCustom` so that I can populate it with values directly. This is the custom element

```
<?php

require_once ('Zend/Form/Element/Select.php');

class Zend_Form_Element_SelectCustom extends Zend_Form_Element_Select
{
    public function init() {
        $this->addMultiOptions(array(
            'NULL' => 'Choose Value',
            '1' => 'First',
            '2' => 'Second',
            '3' => 'Third',
        ));
        return parent::init();
    }
```

The problem is that when I add the new custom element to the form and set it to required, it doesn't fire an error when I don't choose a value.

```
$test = new Zend_Form_Element_SelectCustom('test');
$test->setRequired(true);
$this->addElement($test);
```

I have no idea what's wrong with it. Is there maybe another method that I need to re-initiate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change `'NULL'` to `NULL`. The first is a string with the content "NULL" the latter a empty value. An empty string `''` should be also fine.

```
public function init()
{
    $this->addMultiOptions(array(
        NULL => 'Choose Value', // '' => 'Choose Value'
        '1' => 'First',
        '2' => 'Second',
        '3' => 'Third',
    ));
    return parent::init();
}
```